# Can we add floating label like behaviour in react-native-picker-select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-picker-select

I am using react-native-picker-select component to create select drop down in my react native expo app.
I went through the documention of react-native-picker-select, but could not find anything for adding floating labels like material design.

Is it even possible with react-native-picker-select component or should i use some other alternative?

Comment: anyone , any idea?